# Update table based on column from other table w/ on conflict

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, upsert

I have two tables in Postgres db.

**Table A**

| user | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| mike | 100 |
| bob | 200 |
| alice | 50 |

**Table B**

| group | user | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ace | mike | 10 |
| beta | mike | 15 |
| ace | bob | 2 |
| omega | bob | 15 |
| omega | alice | 25 |

I want to update table b and set quantity equal to table a's quantity * 0.5 joined on username WHERE table b group = xyz.  If a user does not exist in table b, I need to create it with group xyz, username, table a's quantity * 0.5.

I kind of have something here, but it doesn't handle when user does not exist in tableb and I'm not sure it is correct syntax for postgres.

```
update tablea
set quantity = tableb.quantity * 0.5
from tableb
where tablea.username = tableb.username
and tablea.group = ace
```

Comment: @jarlh If you see this, what you do to edit my post?  In the preview it looked good with the tables, but then posting it didn't.  What you change to make it work?  I looked at the edit but it is confusing to know.

Comment: Seems like an empty row is needed before each table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add a unique constraint (if it does not already exist) in the table `TableB` for the combination of the columns `"group"` and `"user"`:

```
ALTER TABLE TableB ADD CONSTRAINT un_group_user UNIQUE("group", "user");
```

Then you can use the `INSERT` statement to insert the users from `TableA` to `TableB` with the [`ON CONFLICT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) clause, so that the rows of the users that exist for group `'xyz'` in `TableB` will be updated:

```
INSERT INTO TableB("group", "user", quantity)
SELECT 'xyz', "user", quantity / 2.0
FROM TableA
ON CONFLICT("group", "user") DO UPDATE SET
quantity = EXCLUDED.quantity;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=febcdfddbe631e23bc27081c0a35d3b0).

Comment: What does quantity = EXCLUDED.quantity; do?
Can I replace 'xyz' with a stored procedure variable?  I couldn't find examples where I could put things in the select like variables so I wasn't sure if I could use variables and text like 'xyz'.

Comment: When there is a conflict in the INSERT statement, all the values that you tried to insert can be accessed with the prefix EXCLUDED. So EXCLUDED."group" is 'xyz', EXCLUDED."user" is the value of the column "user" and EXCLUDED.quantity is the value quantity / 2.0. You can find more here: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-upsert/. You can replace 'xyz' with anything that evaluates to a string.

Comment: @Michael this is the name of the column in your sample data. It is enclosed inside double quotes because group is a reserved word.

Comment: @Michael 'xyz' is a string value that you mention in your question that you want to insert. "user" is the name of the column.

Comment: In my actual db, the names of the quantity field is quantity (table a) and balance (table b), but when I do quantity = EXCLUDED.balance; I get ERROR:  column excluded.balance does not exist
LINE 5: quantity = EXCLUDED.balance;

Comment: @Michael check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=29cdee72d36c6f0c83fa22bbd3d3da19

Comment: How can I ensure that postgres knows which columns from tableA should be compared for `conflict` from tableA if the columns don't have the same name ? Is it the order of which the select statement select the columns in the `tableA` that dictates that ?

Comment: @moth Yes, it is the order. The statement `INSERT INTO TableB("group", "user", quantity) SELECT 'xyz', "user", quantity / 2.0...` tries to assign the string literal `'xyz'` to the column `"group"` and the value of the column `"user"` of TableA to the column `"user"` of TableB.